# Android SeekBar preference for AudioManager?

Tags: java, android, android-preferences, seekbar, android-audiomanager

How to make a `seekbar preference` to change the volume of media in Android?

I have tried [RoboBunnies example](http://robobunny.com/wp/2011/08/13/android-seekbar-preference/) and [thecodeproject by mike114](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/android/seekbar_preference.aspx) but none of them have worked for me. How I want it to look is the title and summary above the `seekbar` then to the right of the `seekbar` a precentage of how loud the media volume is.

Comment: Here is a sample project showing using `SeekBar` to adjust volume: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/SystemServices/Volume

Comment: @CommonsWare the one place I forgot to look was in this thing called a book wonder how that didn't come across my head. Anyways thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the following library [aniqroid](http://code.google.com/p/aniqroid/) and it comes with a class that creates a seekbar preference.